# Partial eta squared for each predictor in aov

Tags: mixed-model, effect-size

I am testing the following model:

```
mdl <- aov(score ~ status * evaDim * dimManip + Error(id / (status * evaDim)), data = XL)
```

with `status`and `evaDim` as within factors and `dimManip` as between factor. I would like to obtain the partial eta squared *for each* of the 7 terms in the model. I tried with `etaSquared(mdl)` from the package `lsr` but it returns an error:

```
Error in etaSquared(mdl) : "x" must be a linear model object
```

How could I calculate them?

Comment: How is partial eta-squared or even "total" R-squared defined in a model with correlated errors?

Comment: @MichaelM To be honest, I don't know. It is just that when I do the same analysis with SPSS partial eta squares of each effect are included in the output. My goal is to compute these same effect sizes using R.